# Container for listview section content on react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a listview with sections including section headers, i wan't to contain section contents(Each section content) in a container and add border to it. how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample code which has border/separator for different rows in listView. renderSeparator is the function you should be looking for. Hope it helps.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  separator: {
    flex: 1,
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
  },
});

class ListViewDemo extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <ListView
      style={styles.container}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(data) => <View><Text>{data}</Text></View>}
      renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style=
      {styles.separator} />} // See this line. renderSeperator is responsible for providing the border.
     />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but it will not render when there is section header below it.

Comment: I am not sure on what do you exactly mean by section header below. But if renderSeperator doesn't work for you. You can add border in the renderRow function itself. Something like :
    <View>
       <View style={styles.outerBorder}>
         <View style={styles.actualContent}>
           //UI components
         </View>
       </View>
     </View>